# Norm on unitisation of a $C^\ast$ algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

In the theory of $C^\ast$ algebras there exists the following theorem:

If $A$ is a $C^\ast$ algebra and $\widetilde{A}$ denotes its unitisation then there exists exactly one norm that extends the norm on $A$ and makes $\widetilde{A}$ into a $C^\ast$ algebra.

This theorem is proved for example in Murphy on page 40. The only property of a $C^\ast$ algebra that is not already satisfied by the usual norm on $\widetilde{A}$ is $\|a\|^2 = \|a^\ast a\|$. The usual norm on $\widetilde{A}$ is defined as $\|(a,\lambda)\| = \|a\| + \lambda$. Let's for the sake of this question assume that $A$ is unital with unit $e$. Then the proof in Murphy endows $\widetilde{A}$ with the norm $\|(a,\lambda)\| = \|a + \lambda e \| + |\lambda|$.

Then we should have:

$$ \|(a,\lambda)\|^2 = \|(a,\lambda)^\ast (a,\lambda)\|$$

I tried to verify this but it seems to be wrong:

$$ \|(a,\lambda)\|^2 = (\|a + \lambda e\| + |\lambda|)^2 = \|a + \lambda e\|^2 + 2 |\lambda|  \|a + \lambda e\|+ |\lambda|^2$$

but

$$\begin{align} 
\|(a,\lambda)^\ast (a,\lambda)\| &= \|(a^\ast a + \lambda a^\ast + \overline{\lambda}a, \lambda \overline{\lambda})\| \\
&= \| a^\ast a + \lambda a^\ast + \overline{\lambda}a + \lambda \overline{\lambda} e\| + |\lambda|^2 \\
&=\|a^\ast (a + \lambda) + \overline{\lambda}(a + \lambda)\| + |\lambda|^2\\
&=\|(a^\ast + \overline{\lambda})(a + \lambda)\| + |\lambda|^2 \\
&= \|(a+\lambda)^\ast (a + \lambda)\| + |\lambda|^2\\
&=  \|(a+\lambda)\|^2 + |\lambda|^2\\
&\neq \|a + \lambda e\|^2 + 2 |\lambda|  \|a + \lambda e\|+ |\lambda|^2
\end{align}$$

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The norm on the direct sum $A \oplus B$ of two C*-algebras is the maximum norm $$\lVert (a,b) \rVert = \max\{\lVert a\rVert, \lVert b\rVert\},$$ not the $\ell_1$-norm that you write: an example that helps me remember this is to consider $A=C(K)$, $B = C(L)$ and to note that $A \oplus B$ should be isomorphic to $C(K \sqcup L)$.

Since Murphy identifies $\widetilde{A}$ with $A \oplus \mathbb C$ via $(a,\lambda) \mapsto (a + \lambda, \lambda)$, the norm you should consider on
$\widetilde{A}$ is $\lVert(a,\lambda)\rVert = \max\{\lVert a+\lambda\rVert,\lvert\lambda\rvert\}$ and a small modification of your calculations shows that this works.

---

Since Murphy doesn't spell it out explicitly: In the non-unital case, the norm on the unitisation is
$$
\lVert (a,\lambda) \rVert = \sup_{\lVert b \rVert \leq 1} \lVert ab+\lambda b\rVert.
$$

Comment: Thank you, your answer is helpful to me. I have to admit though that I'm a bit skeptical: In the proof I mention Murphy seems to define the norm on $\widetilde{A}$ as 
$$ \|(a,\lambda)\| = \|\varphi(a,\lambda)\| = \|(a + \lambda e, \lambda)\| = \|a + \lambda e\| + |\lambda|$$
And there is no indication that the meaning of $\|\cdot\|$ changes into that of the $\sup$ norm there.

Comment: Murphy says *direct sum* and implies that $\varphi \colon \widetilde{A} \to A \oplus \mathbb{C}$. He does *not* say that the norm is given as in the last expression in your comment. Try your calculation with $\max$ as I said and check that this works and use uniqueness of the norm... Compare also with Example 2.4 and Exercise 1.1.

Comment: This is one of the more enlightening posts I've seen. I never would have thought to make the connection to continuous functions.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Thank you. In fact, it is always a good idea to consider the dictionary {commutative C\*-algebras} $\leftrightarrow$ {spaces of continuous functions} and {commutative von Neumann algebras} $\leftrightarrow$ {bounded measurable functions} to understand basic constructions in operator theory. For example, the unitization of $C_0(X)$ corresponds to the one-point compactification and a long list can be found here: http://mathoverflow.net/q/82871

Comment: It's sort of unexpected that the proof distinguishes two cases ($A$ unital and $A$ non-unital). It seems odd that one would ever be interested in considering the unitisation if $A$ is already unital.

Comment: And now I'm skeptical about the norm you give for the non-unital case. In the proof the map $\varphi: \widetilde{A}\to M(A)$ maps $(a,\lambda) \to (L_a, \mathrm{id}\lambda)$ (multiplication by $a$ and $\lambda$) and the norm on the multiplier algebra is $\|(L,R)\|=\|L\| = \|R\|$. Shouldn't then be the norm in the proof of the non-unital case be 
$$ \|\varphi(a,\lambda)\| = \|L_a\| = \|I\lambda\|$$
I see that this is not true but I don't see why.

Comment: I think I understand. It doesn't map to $(L_a, L_{\lambda)}$ it maps to $(L_{a+\lambda}, R_{a+\lambda})$. And then your norm fits.

Comment: @Student: Yes, your second comment is correct and that's how I found the expression :-)